# Generics: Interface to parameter list

Tags: typescript

Is something like this pseudo code possible without passing an object?

```
interface IArgs {
    name: string;
    age: number
}

function getInfo<T>(...T) {
    return ...;
}

getInfo<IArgs>("Bob", 50); // OK
getInfo<IArgs>("Bob"); // Error: parameter "age" is missing
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible with `...T` to have a type check control. Why you don't use simple:

```
function getInfo<T>(args: T[]) // if you need to pass an array
{
    return null;
}
```

or

```
function getInfo<T>(arg: T) // for just simple argument
{
    return null;
}
```

Then you will receive correct compile-time validation messages eg.:

```
getInfo<IArgs>({ name: "Bob" }); // Error: property "age" is missing
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe declare your interface this way:

```
interface IArgs {
    name: string;
    age?: number;
}
```

The `?` makes the property optional.